# Can 来 be used as a 虚词?

Tags: grammar, word

来 usually means "to come".

In this sentence from an online database: 
旱区人民需要我们的帮助来渡过难关

来 does not seem to me being used in its lexical meaning here, but rather containing a grammatical expression of finality "in order to".

Am i wrong, or is this a different usage of it?

Comment: `虚词` is difficult to me, but I think it's a different usage, to express the following phrase as the aim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ABC** calls this a **连词**, which they explain like this:

> Conjunction
>
> Liáncí 连词
>
> A conjunction is a word that joins phrases or sentences together to form a larger sentence or chunk of thought. Some examples include érqiě 'furthermore', suīrán 'although', suǒyǐ 'therefore', jiù 'then' and yàoburán 'otherwise'.

here's **ABC**'s relative entry for 来:

> CONJ.(in order) to
>
> 唱个歌儿来凑热闹
>
> chàng ge gēr lái còu rènao
>
> sing a song to liven things

Here's some other examples from the *A Chinese English Dictionary*:

> 7 (used between a verbal expression and a verb or between two verbal expressions) in order to
>
> 大家想办法来解决。
>
> Dàjiā xiǎng bànfǎ lái jiějué.
>
> Let's think of a way to solve the problem.
>
> 我们得尽一切力量来完成计划。
>
> Wǒmen děi jìn yīqiè lìliang lái wánchéng jìhuà.
>
> We must do all we can to implement the plan.
>
> 你又能用什么理由来说服他呢？
>
> Nǐ yòu néng yòng shénme lǐyóu lái shuōfú tā ne？
>
> And what arguments can you use to convince him?

Comment: What is "ABC" ?

Comment: The **ABC Chinese-English Dictionary** - an essential for English speakers learning Chinese, no matter what level.

Comment: Agree with this answer, and 连词 is a type of 虚词, to strictly answer OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

The summary of 来's usage, as a complement to user3306356's answer.

You can use 来 as a concrete verb, as in `奥巴马来北京见维尼熊`, which you already know.

Less concrete it is when 来 is used in some verb serializations, as in `过来`, `上来`, the main verb is 过 or 上, 来 only functions as an indication of "towards me". Sometimes 来 is used metaphorically, as in `我醒来了`.

Even less concrete is in `让我来问一个问题吧`. You don't literally "come" to ask the question, but 来 grabs your attention and gives you a sense of what is about to come. This falls into the 虚词 category.

In your example 来 indicates a purpose, and it also falls into the 虚词 category. If you think like a linguist, you can see the relation between "in order to" and "to come".

There are even less concrete cases:

- `这个人三十来岁。`--来 means "about".
- `一来脑子好，二来动作快。`——来 is put after a number to indicate that you are
  enumerating.
- `我吃饭来。`——来 is put after an action to indicate the past present tense. You
  see 来着 more often, but sometimes 来 is also used.
- `八月里来桂花香。`——来 means nothing. It's just a 语气助词. You use it to glue things together. It is less common in mandarin, but commonly seen in lyrics and some dialects.