# Meaning of 来 as in 你来给我们评评理

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> 你**来**给我们评评理

Three people are discussing something. One of them asks another to be judge on who's right.

What's the exact meaning of 来 here? Since three of them are already together, it shouldn't be "come here".

Comment: What is "come" doing in "How come you are not an administrator after ten years with the company"?

Comment: We seem to get a number of these questions: (1) [The grammatical component of 来 in this sentence](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/27076) (2) [来 + verb to indicate future](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/35944) (3) [What does 来 mean in 他想一切办法来验证这个理论 and 我们设了个陷阱来抓狐狸?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/37250) (4) [Can 来 be used as a 虚词?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/10385)

Comment: It IS "come here", however, "here" is not a position, it's a "context". For example, imaging the following conversation between three people in good relationship: A:今晚我们吃什么？(started a context about dinner) B:去XX吧，那里的YY贼好吃。 C said to B:还吃YY啊，你看你都胖成啥样了？(started a new sub-context about B's body). B look at C from head to to foot, and said to A:你来给我们评评理，看看到底谁胖？ In this example, A is definitely in a context he/she started, however, he/she is not in the sub-context about B's body, so B invite A to join/come/来 this sub-context go give an opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "来", "come" here acts as a form of "invitation", inviting someone to give an opinion or judgement.

Like, "come, give us your view on this matter"

Answer (score 2):

"来“ in the sentence means that the speaker is asking the third person to join their conversation and resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> 你来给我们评评理

You are right, we shouldn't take its literal meaning here "*to come here*".

来, here in the context, is used to invite for comment.  Other examples:  让我来(let me do it or I will cover it). 你来(You do it).  不，我不来(No, I won't do it.)

This dictionary definition addresses it:

> 用在动词性短语前面，表示要做某事(preceding a verbal phrase, denoting *will do something*)

> E. g. 我来说几句。

Comment: It might be a usage I'm not aware of. I thought the nuance of 来 as in 让我来 (let me do it), or 我来解决这个事 (I'll solve that matter) was mostly found in the first person （我）or with other causative verbs (让）. But the more I read the OP's sentence, the more I'm convinced it could just be as you say

Answer (score 0):

Person A or B calls person C  to 'come' judging the issue because the issue is right in front of them

Notice, we use [来 + V] when the object is close to us, and we use [去 + V] when the object is not close to us

Example:

我來開車 (the car is close by or you are in the car)

我去開車 (the car is not near by or even insigh)

Comment: I've seen the same question asked about 去 which is odd to me because this is exactly how we talk in english

Comment: @ 小奥利奥 are you referring to [this + n] 'and ['that + n] ; [go + v] and [come + v']?

Comment: I'm talking about [go + v] with 去 and [come + v'] with 来

Answer (score 0):

I think "来" here means the start of an action.